# How do you create a password list for a forensics case based on the evidence

Tags: encryption, password-cracking, forensics

I would like to compile a list of strings and filenames based on digital evidence obtained to make them into a password dictionary. I understand that FTK offers this solution but it's not free to use.

Is there any tools that can help aid this process instead of manually copying each string?

Comment: Do you mean a "password dictionary" (password list?) to try an brute force someone's password?
John the Ripper has the ability to brute force against password lists you can compile from hand and tell the program how to manipulate etc. If that's what you're looking for. http://www.openwall.com/john/

Comment: Exactly this. I want to add `crunch` to the list of programs to use. (Also, try rewording your question so it's not so short and unclear to avoid flags and downvotes)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as there is nowhere that states I want to break into a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Bulk Extractor](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Bulk_extractor). I haven't used it before, but have heard good things.